# How to retrieve a file from Hyper.sh container?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

We are using hyper.sh to test JavaScript exams.  The call to the hyper.sh API creates a container that uses a bash script to clone the submission, install dependencies, and pipe test results to /tmp/student_results.

Previously, we utilized dockerode in this process and were able to call getArchive as part of a callback provided to container.run().  The Hyper.sh CLI doesn't have the ability to provide a callback or to get file archives it seems.

We can echo the file contents to stdout and retrieve the logs from the hyper containers, but we don't have a way to know when the process is done.  The hyper CLI lets you wait for a container to finish but the API does not.

Our current solution for this problem would be to curl the contents of the file to a webhook in our application.  Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Try using https://docs.hyper.sh/Reference/API/2016-04-04%20[Ver.%201.23]/Container/logs.html with `follow=1`, this api should finish when the container finishes. Or you can use attach with `stream=1` and `stdout=1` https://docs.hyper.sh/Reference/API/2016-04-04%20[Ver.%201.23]/Container/attach.html. That also should finish when the container finishes. So both (assuming they work) are smarter then the existing approach.